# Building a 4-bit S-box with a 4-uniform DDT

Tags: algorithm-design, s-boxes, differential-analysis

I am looking for a 4-bit S-box which has **only** 4s in its difference distribution table (except the top left corner) but I was not able to find one in the literature.

Has such an S-box been already published? If not, is it theoretically possible to reach this property? If so, how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All $4\times4$ bit S-boxes have been classified. It is possible to reach a maximum differential of 4 as well as optimum nonlinearity.

SERPENT used optimal $4\times 4$ S-boxes with respect to differential cryptanalysis. So does PRESENT, to the best of my knowledge.

Some links

- 2011 - Markku-Juhani O. Saarinen, [Cryptographic Analysis of All 4 × 4-Bit S-Boxes](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/218.pdf)
- 2015 - Zhang et.al., [A New Classification of 4-bit Optimal S-boxes and its Application to PRESENT, RECTANGLE and SPONGENT](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/433.pdf)

SAGE is a good way to learn about and experiment with S-boxes.

- [Sage: S-Boxes and Their Algebraic Representations](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/cryptography/sage/crypto/sbox.html)

**Edit:** None of the optimal Sboxes' representatives from Saarinen have the property of all 4's you want. I have no time, but I believe it can be proved using Theorem 1

[image: Theorem 1]

in [Blondeau-Nyberg](http://file:///Users/serdarboztas/Downloads/Blondeau-Nyberg2013_Chapter_NewLinksBetweenDifferentialAnd.pdf) which originally appeared in Eurocrypt 94  [Chabaud-Vaudenay](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0053450) that such a DDT pattern would yield weak S-boxes against linear cryptanalysis. Here $n=m=4,$  $cor_x(a\cdot x \oplus b\cdot F(x))$ is the correlation bias of the corresponding linear characteristic, and $P[\delta \stackrel{F}{\rightarrow} \Delta]$ is the diferential probability.

Comment: Although the maximum value in the DDTs of SERPENT and PRESENT is 4, some entries are also equal to 2: I'm looking for an S-box whose DDT contains 4s only.

Comment: I don't know if there is an equivalence class that contains such an example. So you want 4's and 0's.

Comment: why don't you go to the table at the end of the Saarinen paper and check the DDT of the 16 equiv class representatives using Sage?